# Results of reduce and count differ in pyspark

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark

For my spark trials, I have downloaded the [NY taxi csv files](http://www.andresmh.com/nyctaxitrips/) and merged them into a single file, nytaxi.csv . I then saved this in hadoop fs. I am using spark on yarn with 7 nodemanagers.

I am connecting to spark over Ipython notebook.

Here is a sample python script for counting the number of lines in nytaxi.csv.

```
nytaxi=sc.textFile("hdfs://bigdata6:8020/user/baris/nytaxi/nytaxi.csv")
filtered=nytaxi.filter(lambda x:"distance" not in x)
splits = filtered.map(lambda x: float(x.split(",")[9]))
splits.cache()
splits.count()
```

This returns 73491693.
However when I try to count lines by the following code, it returns a value around 803000.

```
def plusOne (sum, v):
    #print sum, v
    return sum + 1;
splits.reduce(plusOne)
```

I wonder why the results vary.
Thanks

A sample line from csv:
u'740BD5BE61840BE4FE3905CC3EBE3E7E,E48B185060FB0FF49BE6DA43E69E624B,CMT,1,N,2013-10-01 12:44:29,2013-10-01 12:53:26,1,536,1.20,-73.974319,40.741859,-73.99115,40.742424'

Comment: Can you provide some section from csv file you are using?

Comment: Added a sample line into question text.

Comment: From my understanding you are getting output corresponding to only one partition and not whole RDD. I am able to reproduce this issue and if no of partitions are reduce to 1 then output in  both count and reduce matches. I am still learning about spark so not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is as Daniel specified in that the operation used in `reduce` must be associative and commutative. [Here's the reason from the source itself](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L961):

```
val reducePartition: Iterator[T] => Option[T] = iter => {
  if (iter.hasNext) {
    Some(iter.reduceLeft(cleanF))
  } else {
    None
  }
}
```

Notice that the `reduce` done on each partition is a simple delegation to it's iterator's `reduceLeft`. This would not cause any problems as it is just an accumulation of values.

```
val mergeResult = (index: Int, taskResult: Option[T]) => {
  if (taskResult.isDefined) {
    jobResult = jobResult match {
      case Some(value) => Some(f(value, taskResult.get))
      case None => taskResult
    }
  }
}
```

But, the merging of the partitions is the problem. Here's how it would break down in your example (assume a 40 count over 4 evenly split partitions):

```
A = 10; B = 10; C = 10; D = 10 //Local reductions. Everything ok
A added in = 10 //Still ok
B added in = f(10, 10) = 11 //Because your definition of f is (first + 1)
                            //This drops the second param of 10
C added in = f(11, 10) = 12 //Again, only adding 1 instead of the actual 10 count
```

So, you should prefer `count`, or do as Daniel suggest and `map`, or you have a third option to do an `aggregate`

```
 rdd.aggregate(0)(_+1, _+_)
```

This would seed the count with a 0, keep adding 1 to the accumulator locally, then add the two accumulators together in the merge.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for [`RDD.reduce()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.reduce) says:

> Reduces the elements of this RDD using the specified commutative and associative binary operator.

`def plusOne(sum, v): return sum + 1` is not commutative. It completely ignores one of the parameters. So you are seeing undefined behavior. (I recommend considering why the function must be commutative. If you understand that, you understand Spark a little better!)

The solution is to use `RDD.count()` instead. But if you insist on using `reduce()`, this is how you would do it:

```
def count(rdd):
  return rdd.map(lambda x: 1).reduce(lambda a, b: a + b)
```

Answer (score 1):

**THIS IS NOT COMPLETE ANSWER**

Since i can not put my findings in comment so i am writing them here.

I am able to reproduce your issue with a much simpler example.

```
data = xrange(1, 10000)
len(data) #output => 9999
xrangeRDD = sc.parallelize(data, 8)
print xrangeRDD.count()
def plusOne (v,sum):
  #print sum, v
  return v + 1;
a = xrangeRDD.reduce(plusOne)
print a
```

**Output**

```
9999
1256
```

For `xrangeRDD = sc.parallelize(data, 4)`

**Output**

```
9999
2502
```

For `xrangeRDD = sc.parallelize(data, 1)`

**Output**

```
9999
9999
```

Since i am only varying number of partitions and that is varying the output of reduce i think that reduce is only giving you output of one partition as suggested by the pattern here.

I am still learning how spark work. So i am not able to get entire logic here why this is happening. I hope that with this extra detail someone might be able to explain reason behind this.